# Can you have two named groups in the same part of a string?

Tags: .net, regex

I am using Regular Expression Named Groups in .NET to find parts of a scanned bar-code string. The RegEx can be added in a configuration so the system can be adapted for different bar-code layouts.

This works fine, but I have one situation that I can not get to work:

Example barcode:

```
17C002101/1803
```

Regex:

```
(?<LotNumber>.{9})(\/)(?<ExpDate>.{4})
```

This works fine and extracts this:

LotNumber: 17C002101
ExpDate: 1803

Now I also need to extract "TestCode" and that is actually a part of the "LotNumber" match, in this case the last four digits so "2101"

Is there a way of doing this, or do I need to create multiple regex for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your third group is a part of another and no overlaps happen, you can simply nest those groups.

```
(?<LotNumber>.{5}(?<TestCode>.{4}))(\/)(?<ExpDate>.{4})
```